# How can i specify framework version in compass create?

Tags: bundler, compass-sass, zurb-foundation

i have two gem versions of foundation framework installed.
i want to specify version of framework before create project.

```
compass create <project-name> -r zurb-foundation --using foundation
```

i can create only with current framework version now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can run multiple versions of foundation. There is some documentation on how to do that at:

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html

under *Running multiple versions*

I wanted to have the latest version of Foundation 3 as well as the most current version of 4. You can check the available versions here:

https://rubygems.org/gems/zurb-foundation/versions

I saw that 3.2.5 was the latest version. You can install it by running gem.

`gem install zurb-foundation --version 3.2.5`

now if you run `gem list`

you will see something like `zurb-foundation (4.0.3, 4.0.2, 3.2.5)` at the end

Now, if you run compass it will automatically use the latest version so we will need to use bundler instead. Create a new directory and create a Gemfile.

```
mkdir myApp
cd myApp
touch Gemfile
```

then edit the Gemfile with your editor of choice so it looks like this:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
# Replace 4.0.3 with the version of Foundation you want to use
gem "zurb-foundation", "3.2.5"
gem "compass"
```

then run bundler to exec compass:

`bundle exec compass create . -r zurb-foundation --using foundation`

this will build out everything just as compass does normally, but with the specific version you specify.

Comment: i have seen foundation guide and tried it. but problem is created project is with latest version of foundation careless to mentioned version in Gemfile. you tried this way already ?

Comment: this worked exactly as i wrote, as long as you install and confirm the correct gem. and then run bundle exec compass create ... after creating the gem file. It was good to know because I am still working on foundation 3 projects while testing out the new foundation 4.

Comment: maybe if you could post from `gem list` and the contents of your `Gemfile`

Comment: i created some scripts that might be useful if you are doing this frequently: https://github.com/manofstone/zurb-foundation-useful-scripts

Comment: content of gemfile: source "https://rubygems.org"
gem "zurb-foundation", "3.2.5"
gem "compass"   and gem list zurb-foundation give me 2 versions 4.0.4 3.2.5

Comment: i use windows 7. are u trying on linux on windows? if i remove Gemfile it give me 'there is no Gemfile' but if it exist, it use latest version of foundation.

Comment: I haven't used compass on windows, but I think using cygwin is a common way of installing rvm, ruby, gems, bundle/r, compass, etc.

Comment: did you ever get this resolved? Another solution would be to use rvm to use a specific version of the zurb-foundation gem.

Comment: sorry for late response. i installed bundler 1.5.3 - i couldn't find bundler in gem list however i didn't get any error for that and i remember i have installed it - and every thing works perfect now. you can add this bundler install to your great answer.