# Zurb Foundation - How to change project template?

Tags: ruby, compass-sass, zurb-foundation, webstorm

Everytime I build a project I have to move the directories around.  We also use Require.js, so I also have to copy and paste from a previous project the javascript initialization file that imports all of the foundation functionality.

I create these projects using either Webstorm 5's Foundation project template or via the command line using:

```
compass create my_project -r zurb-foundation --using foundation
```

Where would I go to modify these project templates?  Is this down in some ruby path?  Is there a project manifest file or something?

Thanks,
Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get the location of your gem installs from GEM_HOME

`echo $GEM_HOME`

in my case I get something like this:

`/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286`

then in the `gems` directory you may see several instances of foundation. in my case an `ls' reveals the following directories:

```
zurb-foundation-3.2.1
zurb-foundation-3.2.2
zurb-foundation-3.2.5
zurb-foundation-4.0.2
zurb-foundation-4.0.3
```

if you are going to use `compass create my_project -r zurb-foundation --using foundation` it will pull from the latest version, in my case 4.0.3.

If you want to edit the compass blueprint directly, it is in:

`zurb-foundation-4.0.3/templates/project`

by modifying these files it will do as you intend, however, if you ever run `gem update` it is possible it will pull down a new version of foundation and start using that instead.

You might want to consider creating a fork of the foundation project, make the changes you need, and use bundle to create your compass projects. You could easily even create a script to do that.

Check it out on the [Zurb Foundation 4 Documentation Page for Sass](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/sass.html), under "Creating a project from Git"

Comment: I added a couple of scripts that might be useful to you https://github.com/manofstone/zurb-foundation-useful-scripts

Comment: Thanks. Do you, by chance, know how I can have a foundation 3.2.5 project live alongside a v4.0.3 one?  I did a gem update yesterday and found I could no longer compile the older one, so I downgraded back go 3.2.5.  When you do a gem install foundation, isn't it just creating a symlink somewhere pointing to the latest one?  If so, can't I just re-write the symlink depending on which project I'm working on?

Comment: not sure about the symlink, but I answered how to run multiple versions of zurb foundation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175775/how-can-i-specify-framework-version-in-compass-create/15192829#15192829