# Managing multiple versions of a Ruby Gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, zurb-foundation

I'm a newbie, but I have a question regarding managing different versions of a gem, in my case, zurb-foundation.  A new version just came out and I did a gem update and it made my older versions of the framework no longer compile.

My project contains a config.rb file that starts with

```
require 'zurb-foundation'
```

How does Ruby know to use the latest version of this?  Is there a symlink somewhere pointing to the latest version?  If so, I was thinking I could just re-write this symlink depending on which project I'm currently working in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use RVM to manage multiple versions of ruby and gems.
Visit followings links to have an idea of rvm and to install.

https://rvm.io/

https://rvm.io/rvm/install/

Comment: This sounds like a great idea.  Sandbox the whole environment on a per-project basis.  Thanks!

Comment: Scott, you also lock in the whole environment in with Bundler. RVM makes it more complicated with its Gemsets in my opinion. Gemsets can also not be stored in source control like the Gemfile in Bundler.

Answer (score 6):

If you have multiple projects that use different versions of a gem you probably want to have a look at Bundler.

http://gembundler.com/

Bundler makes managing Ruby gems a breeze. This is highly recommended!

Comment: i talked about how to use bundler / bundle to maintain multiple versions of foundation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15175775/how-can-i-specify-framework-version-in-compass-create/15192829#15192829