# Using Zurb Foundation 4 on Foundation 3 projects

Tags: css, responsive-design, zurb-foundation

I have an existing project using Zurb Foundation 3 I have been working on for a couple of months.

I also need to start a NEW project for a different client and want to use version 4.

How can I best do this, without messing up the old project?

Comment: Have you take a look to the [migration guide](http://foundation.zurb.com/migration.php)?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to have and use both without any issue.  Every version of gem that is installed in ruby is kept from what I've seen, so the Foundation 3 gem will remain if you upgrade to Foundation 4.  The only way you could mess up a previous Foundation 3 project is if you do a force upgrade.  Check out this post [How can i specify framework version in compass create?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15175775/2236808), it has some useful information regarding the multiple versions of Foundation as well.